# Collapsing all Slickgrid trees on page load

Tags: slickgrid

How to have Slickgrid's collapsible trees start out collapsed on page load, rather than expanded?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the _collapsed property to true for the nodes with childs:

```
d["_collapsed"] = true
```

Comment: For me it worked a bit different. Slickgrid only checked (on initial load!) whether the attribute _collapsed is available. If it was available it collapsed the sub tree, totally ignoring whether it was set to true or false.

Answer (score 1):

For me calling `dataView.collapseAllGroups()` prior to rendering the table was sufficient to start up with collapsed groups.

Note that slickgrid currently has a bug concerning groups: [Slickgrid grouping expand/collapse strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007265/slickgrid-grouping-expand-collapse-strange-behaviour) which can be fixed using [this commit](https://github.com/icoxfog417/SlickGrid/commit/72d6e8e2b94fdb445caf3658d8699458ba422ff8)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in a demo (no DB).  You'll have to get the actual number of groups from your DB, then just loop through the grid and close 'em all:

```
for(var i=0; i<7; i++) {
  dataView.collapseGroup(i);
}
```